# What are $A_1 = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [0,k), A_2 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{k}),A_3 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}[0,\frac{1}{k})$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In the exercise it says "calculate" the following sets:

$$A_1 = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [0,k)$$ $$A_2 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{1}{k})$$$$A_3 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}[0,\frac{1}{k})$$$$ A_4 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (\frac{k-1}{k},\frac{k+1}{k})$$

Now I'm not entirely sure with my results, I have:

Since obviously $k \rightarrow \infty $, I would guess that $A_1 = \mathbb{R}_+$, but I'm not sure since $A_1$ is an open interval and therefore cannot contain all positive real numbers?!

For $A_2$ I have $A_2 = \varnothing$ since the sequence $(\frac{1}{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, but since $0 \not \in A_2 \Rightarrow A_2 = \varnothing$?!

For $A_3$, $0\in A_3 \Rightarrow A_3 = \{0\}$

$A_4 = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (\frac{k-1}{k},\frac{k+1}{k})= \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (1-\frac{1}{k},1+\frac{1}{k})$ and since $(\frac{1}{k}) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow A_3 = \varnothing$?

Is that correct?

Comment: Either you mistook $\bigcup$ for $\bigcap$, or you got none of them right.

Comment: Oh sorry, all except the first one are $\bigcap$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $A_1$ is almost right (I assume that $0\notin\mathbb R_+$). You should have $A_1=[0,\infty)$. If $x\ge 0$ then $x\in [0,k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$ (say for $k=\lfloor x\rfloor +1$), hence $x\in A_1$. And if $x<0$ then $x\notin [0,k)$ for all $k$, hence $x\notin A_1$.

You are right, $A_2=\emptyset$. If $x\le 0$ then $x\notin (0,\frac1{42})$, hence $x\notin A_2$. If $x>0$ then there exixts $k$ with $k>\frac1x$ and then $x\notin (0,\frac1k)$.

You are right. The argument is the same as for $A_2$, except that $0\in[0,\frac1k)$ for all $k$, hence $0\in A_3$.

$A_4$: Note that $0$ is not always the center of the world. Hint: You have $\frac{k-1}{k}<1<\frac{k+1}k$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

What you should focus on is that the intervals $I_k=[0,k)$ satisfy $I_k \subset I_{k+1}$. Thus 
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{k=N}I_k=I_N.$$ Now this can lead you to guess that 
$$A_1 = [0, \infty).$$
Of course you need to prove it by showing $A_1 \subseteq [0,\infty)$ and vice versa.

Try using these ideas for all other $A_i$'s.

Comment: The OP already has "answers" for $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$. They have asked if their "answers" are correct.